# How to wait for Wikibase edit links to finish loading

Tags: mediawiki, wikidata, wikidata-api

I would like to write a Wikidata gadget, and need to wait for the page to be fully loaded, including the `edit` links next to each statement.

I tried to wait for `wikibase.view.ViewFactoryFactory` but that didn't help - my code begins executing before the edit toolbar is initialized.  What's the best way to do it?

```js
mw.loader.using( [ 'wikibase.view.ViewFactoryFactory' ], function () {
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Received an answer from IRC channel, thanks `nikki`!

```js
    mw.hook('wikibase.entityPage.entityView.rendered').add(function () {
        ....
    });
```